# Php simultaniously click from 2 different browsers shop issue

Tags: php

I have an issue where i coded an item shop and a user can login to his account and buy stuff with points the issue is if the user login from 2 different computer and click on buy on the same time he would get the item twice but paying only once, i would ask how to lock buy per account until a purchase is finished and then move to the next one .
here is my code

```
    public function buyItem(){
        try{
            /*1- Get All Data Necessary*/
            /*Get & Verify Input*/
            $data = $this->verifyInput();
            /*Check If item exists in database And Get Info*/
            $item = $this->getItemFromDb($data->id);
            /*Check if Item is on Sale With this type of currency */
            $this->ifOnSale($item,$data->type);
            /*Check Buyer Amount Of Cash */
            $buyer = $this->getPoints();
            /*load prices */
            $out = $this->getPriceAll($data,$item,$buyer);
            /*Start Checks*/
            /*check if player has enough cash*/
            if ($out->uCash < $out->totalPrice){
                throw new Exception(_LC["er_notenoughcash"]);
            }
            /*start now adding point to player*/
            $this->insertPaidItem($out);
            /*update Cash from account*/
            $this->getCashFromAccount($out);
            /*Add log to data*/
            $this->addLogToItem($out);
            $this->insertPaidItemLog($out,$item);

            return array(
                "alertContent"=>["title"=>self::strtoupper(_LC['shopsuccess']),"text"=>_LC['shopdoneitem'],"type"=>"success"],
                "newPoint"=>$this->getPoints()->point,
                "clickItem"=>"#cs-nav-close"
            );
        }catch (Exception $e){
            return array(
                "alertContent"=>["title"=>self::strtoupper(_LC['error']),"text"=>$e->getMessage(),"type"=>"alert"],
                "newPoint"=>$this->getPoints()->point,
                "clickItem"=>"#cs-nav-close"
            );
        }
    }
```

i would like to figure out a way to avoid this type of bugs in the future and thank you

Comment: It should not be possible to uphold sessions (for the same user) on two different machines...

Comment: @HonkderHase Why not? I frequently log into the same website on my PC and on my phone, for instance. Also, race conditions can easily happen within one "session", e.g. with multiple browser tabs, or simply clicking a button twice on a laggy connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as a *race condition*, and the solution is to make operations *atomic*.

If I'm reading correctly, these are the key lines:

```
/*check if player has enough cash*/
if ($out->uCash < $out->totalPrice){
    throw new Exception(_LC["er_notenoughcash"]);
}
/*start now adding point to player*/
$this->insertPaidItem($out);
/*update Cash from account*/
$this->getCashFromAccount($out);
```

If we translated this into a physical transaction, it would read like this:

1. The customer *shows you* a £20 note (but doesn't hand it to you)
2. You hand them the product
3. You ask them to hand you the £20 note

The risk is that during step 2, the customer can pass the £20 note they showed you to someone else. You are then left trying to reclaim the product from them.

To avoid this, you could change the transaction to this:

1. The customer *hands you* a £20 note
2. You hand them the product

Now, there is no way for *you* to be out of pocket, but if something goes wrong at step 2, you need to refund the customer.

In PHP, that would look something like this:

```
/*update Cash from account */
/*this method should throw an exception if there is not enough */
$this->getCashFromAccount($out);
try {
    /*start now adding point to player*/
    $this->insertPaidItem($out);
}
catch ( Exception $e ) {
    /*paid item didn't process successfully, refund customer*/
    $this->refundCashToAccount($out);
    /*propagate exception (or wrap it as appropriate)*/
    throw $e;
}
```

As an aside, all your functions seem to be relying on a lot of context; they will be clearer and more reusable if they take the specific values they need to do their job:

```
/*update Cash from account */
/*this method should throw an exception if there is not enough */
$this->getCashFromAccount($buyer, $out->totalPrice);
try {
    /*start now adding point to player*/
    $this->insertPaidItem($buyer, $item);
}
catch ( Exception $e ) {
    /*paid item didn't process successfully, refund customer*/
    $this->refundCashToAccount($buyer, $out->totalPrice);
    /*propagate exception (or wrap it as appropriate)*/
    throw $e;
}
```

A common variation of this is to have a separate pot of "reserved" cash, which is *automatically* refunded if a transaction is not confirmed within a certain amount of time (e.g. using a cron job that periodically checks for errored transactions). This is how online card payments often work, for instance: "authorise" an amount of money on the account, process the transaction, then "settle" the money when it succeeds. Whether this is necessary depends largely on how likely it is for `insertPaidItem` to fail.